# Prolog - How do i separate a tuple to be part of my pre-existing list?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to take the following:

```
[a,b,(c,d)]
```

and turn it to

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

I am obtaining [a], [b], and [(c,d)] separately from different findalls and appending them together to obtain the [a,b,(c,d)] list.

Comment: You separate them before appending them all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?- write_canonical([1,2,(3,4)]).
[1,2,','(3,4)]
```

You can see that parenthesis (when contain comma(s)) have a peculiar property: they behave as a structure. Another example

```
?- arg(2,(x,y),A).
A = y.
```

For your problem, I would write

```
?- [user].
|: elem((X,_),X).
|: elem((_,T),X):-elem(T,X).
|: elem(X,X) :- atomic(X).
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.02 sec, 3 clauses
true.
```

and now

```
?- L=[1,2,(3,4)], findall(Y,(member(X,L),elem(X,Y)),F).
L = [1, 2,  (3, 4)],
F = [1, 2, 3, 4].

?- L=[1,2,(3,4),(5),(6,7,8)], findall(Y,(member(X,L),elem(X,Y)),F).
L = [1, 2,  (3, 4), 5,  (6, 7, 8)],
F = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
```

Note this will work only a level depth. To enable arbitrary nesting, should be enough to change the first clause of elem/2:

```
elem((X,_),Y) :- elem(X,Y).
```

Comment: Just a quick reminder that the generic solution for n-tuples  is a source of non-termination (e.g. the query with ```L=[A]```) and should only be used if the task requires it.  Furthermore, you could relax the atomicity condition to a ```dif(X, (_,_))``` to include lists like ```[f(a)]```.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, makes sense! and also learned I can use a  member within a findall, cool!